# USB connection mode options no longer showing in notifications drawer

Tags: usb, usb-debugging, usb-connection-mode

My phone is plugged into my computer via USB - it is charging, but I do not see any options to change the USB connection mode in the notifications drawer. I have seen and used these options in the past, but it is not showing now for some reason. They looked similar to this - https://cdn.arstechnica.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/usb2.png.

For context, I had the phone in 'USB Debugging' mode earlier on, but I've since turned it off - `adb devices` was not listing my phone anyway, although that also has worked in the past.

[image: screenshot of settings and notifications drawer showing lack of USB options, even though the batter is shown as charging]

I am running Android 8.1 on a Nexus 5X.

Comment: Check in Developer Options is in "select USB configuration" if it is set to charging. If so change

Comment: Thanks, I am able to change it there which will suffice for now. The sticky notification to change the USB connection mode has not reappeared in the notifications drawer though.

Comment: Welcome. You can self answer :)